# Load JavaScript before Gutenberg Widget was rendered

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom Gutenberg widget and i want to hide all the widgets before the site was rendered.

I added the code snippet in the custom widget but the JS was loaded to late.

Currently, I see first all the widgets and some seconds later the widgets disappear.

Is there any workaround that the JS was loaded first?

Comment: Please include all relevant code along with your question.

Comment: I have no code, that is the reason why i ask for a code snippet to solve my problem. The goal is to add some javascript code to hide all the other widgets.. but the JS of the widget was load after the page was rendered.